# Does hive bucket mapjoin support full outer join?

Tags: sql, hadoop, join, hive

I have four large bucketed and sorted table A,B,C,D. Each table have about 100M rows. But when I full outer join them together using

```
select sum(1) from A full outer join B on (A.id=B.id) full outer join C on (A.id=C.id) full outer join D on ( A.id=D.id )
```

The result is only about 50M, which is same with inner join. So I wonder if the bucket mapjoin only suppose inner join?

Comment: your join for table D maps the id columns for table A and B not sure if it is typo or not but its better to check it again

Comment: sorry, a written mistake. Have been corrected.

Answer (score 0):

The SMB Map Join is not implemented for the FULL OUTER JOIN, please refer to [HIVE-26938](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-26938) to track the progress of this feature .